# How to check which ContentObserver triggers the onChange method?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, onchange, contentobserver

What I want to do is to have a `Service` with more than one `ContentObserver` registered and check which `ContentObserver` triggers `onChange()` to do specific reactions. I dont know if I just have to include a if/else inside the `onchange()`, or `Overwrite` it to each `ContentObserver`, in either cases I wouldnt know exactly how to do it. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public class SmsObserverService extends Service {

private String BABAS = "babas";
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), true, new SmsObserver(handler));

    //Second observer
    this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI"), true, new SmsObserver(handler));

}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Put your code here
    return null;
}


public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver{

    public SmsObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);


    }
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {          
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        //Where I should check somehow which ContentObserver triggers the onChange


        //This code to the sms log stuff, the call log part will be included
        //when I find out how to check whic observer trigerred the onChange
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query( uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToNext();


        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
        String add = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));


        String protocol = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("protocol"));

        if(protocol == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enviada para: " +add + ", Hora: "+time +" - "+body, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(BABAS, "Enviada para: "+add +" " +"Time: "+time +" - "+body);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recebida de: "+add + ", Hora: "+time +" - "+body, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(BABAS, "Recebida de: "+add +" " +"Time: "+time +" - "+body);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: look my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simply extend `ContentObserver` and add whatever I am missing there.

Comment: That is what I want to do, but I dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

```
mObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);

                    }
                }
            };
```

You can check uri with above method